# Template template parameter partial specialization c++

Tags: c++, templates

Consider the code:

```
template<template<typename,typename> class Container>
class A {
    template<class U, class Allocator>
    void Foo(Container<U, Allocator>*, U);
};
```

Now I want to specialize `A` in the case the Container is a map where the Value and Comparator are known, and create a definition of `Foo` in this case (no specialization of `Foo`). I tried this:

```
template<typename V, typename Comp> template<class U, class Allocator>
void A<std::map<typename, V, Comp, typename>>::Foo(map<U, V, Comp, Allocator>*, U ) {...}
```

But I get the compiling error:`C3200: 'std::map<int,V,Comp,int>' : invalid template argument for template parameter 'Container', expected a class parameter.`

I have looked online and only found similar issues, but I couldn't find a way
to specify only partial template parameter list of a template template.
Is there a way to do it?

EDIT: The only problem is when giving a template class partial specialization is to make it behave as a template with the remaining parameters.
Here it's an attempt to think of a `map<*,Known1,Known2,*>` as a template of only 2 arguments (which can realy be used as the template template parameter of `A`) .

EDIT 2: The compiler I have to use is GCC 4.1.2 that has no support for template aliasing, which, as I understood, is a solution.

Answer (score 5):

The problem is that `A` takes a template template parameter that takes two types:

```
template<template<typename,typename> Container>
class A {
```

But [`std::map`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map) doesn't take two types. It takes four:

```
template<
    class Key,
    class T,
    class Compare = std::less<Key>,
    class Allocator = std::allocator<std::pair<const Key, T> >
> class map;
```

So that's one problem. You will have to generalize your template to the following (also note the missing `class` keyword):

```
template <template <typename...> class Container>
class A { ... };
```

But even with that, at most you could completely explicitly specialize a member function, you can't partially specialize it:

```
template <>
template <>
void A<std::map>::Foo<>(std::map<U, V>*, U) { ... }
```

Comment: I edited the question, I think you misunderstood me, I'm trying to specialize the Container and not the member function.
Also, the map here has two parameters specialized: T = V and Compare = Comp, so the template is supposed to take only two parameters now.

Comment: @OmerRosler `map` takes 4 parameters. The fact that two of them are defaulted doesn't matter. You would have to [make an alias](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9b4de514a9de7f3f).

Comment: I think aliasing is exactly what I was looking for, but how can I make an alias of a template?
Something like 
template<U,Al> template<V, Comp> using M = map<U,V,Comp,Al>